# Read a file from HTTPS using SSL into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, ssl, https

I am trying to read an XML file from HTTPS location using SSL into pandas dataframe.  I found some sample code but am unable to make it work. How would I go about doing it?

```
import requests
urllink='https://www.oasis.oati.com/woa/docs/MISO/MISODocs/CurrentData/2308_Planned_Outages_2017-09-19-18-50-00.xml'

cCert = r'C:/Temp/MISOcert.pfx'
requests.get(urllink, cert=cCert)
```

I am able to read the XML file into dataframe if I place the XML file locally. To do that, I use xml.etree.ElementTree.

But I want to be able to ping the URL directly with the cert and read the XML into dataframe.

Comment: you want to verify the client side? cert arg is for client side and takes a tuple of string  `(cert, key)`, use verify for server side and is a single string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really recommend using verify=False for the requests.get call but the below method worked for me.  It pulls the data and builds the xml document. From there you can load it into the dataframe however you want.

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


def get_data(url):
    response = requests.get(urllink, verify=False)
    return ET.fromstring(response.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = 'https://www.oasis.oati.com/woa/docs/MISO/MISODocs/CurrentData/2308_Planned_Outages_2017-09-19-18-50-00.xml'
    xml_document = get_data(url)
```

Comment: This works great. You dont recommend using verify=false. How would you suggest going about with the True then? Also, a naive question: __name__ == '__main__': what does this do?

Comment: Shyama, verify would otherwise be set to a string representing the path to an SSL certificate (often using the [certifi](https://pypi.org/project/certifi/) library). The `__name__` variable is set by python at runtime. In this case, the file is used as a sort of "main method" file so the code in the if block WILL be executed. However, if it were being imported as a module, it would not.